# TikZ: Non-intersecting edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

**GIVEN**: The code snipset below which shall draw a graph of non-intersecting edges.

```
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,node distance=3cm, initial text=$ $]

  \node[initial, state]   (A)              {$0$};
  \node[state]            (C) [right of=A] {$2$};
  \node[state]            (D) [above of=C] {$3$};
  \node[state]            (E) [right of=D] {$4$};
  \node[state]            (F) [below of=E] {$5$};
  \node[state, accepting] (G) [right of=F] {$6$};

  \path (A) edge [above]     (C);
  \path (C) edge [above]     (D);
  \path (D) edge [above]     (E);
  \path (E) edge [above]     (F);
  \path (F) edge [above]     (G);
  \path (A) edge [bend left] (G);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

**RESULT**:

The edge from A to G intersects with others.

**QUESTION**:

How can this be avoided with an arrow that bends over nodes 3 and 4?

Comment: Welcome! Just change `bend left` to `bend right`: `\path (A) edge [bend right] (G);`.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. It is already great input. But what I meant was to bend the arrow over the nodes 3 and 4. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! The main question is answered by chaining `bend left` to e.g. `bend right`. I am writing this in order to inform you that, even though you are loading the `positioning` library, you are not using is. If you want to use it (and I think you should), change

```
right of=
```

to

```
right=<distance> of
```

where `<distance>` is optional, and if unspecified set to the `node distance`. You are also loading but not using the `arrows` library. If you want to have access to more arrow heads, load `arrows.meta` instead.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,node distance=2.2cm, initial text=\empty]

  \node[initial, state]   (A)              {$0$};
  \node[state]            (C) [right=of A] {$2$};
  \node[state]            (D) [above=of C] {$3$};
  \node[state]            (E) [right=of D] {$4$};
  \node[state]            (F) [below=of E] {$5$};
  \node[state, accepting] (G) [right=of F] {$6$};

  \path (A) edge [above]     (C)
   (C) edge [above]     (D)
   (D) edge [above]     (E)
   (E) edge [above]     (F)
   (F) edge [above]     (G)
   (A) edge [bend right] (G);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: You can change the bending angle and looseness.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,node distance=2.2cm, initial text=\empty]

  \node[initial, state]   (A)              {$0$};
  \node[state]            (C) [right=of A] {$2$};
  \node[state]            (D) [above=of C] {$3$};
  \node[state]            (E) [right=of D] {$4$};
  \node[state]            (F) [below=of E] {$5$};
  \node[state, accepting] (G) [right=of F] {$6$};

  \path (A) edge [above]     (C)
   (C) edge [above]     (D)
   (D) edge [above]     (E)
   (E) edge [above]     (F)
   (F) edge [above]     (G)
   (A) edge [bend left=80,looseness=1.7] (G);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are worried about the overestimate of the bounding box, use the `bbox` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning,bbox}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,node distance=2.2cm, initial text=\empty,bezier
  bounding box]

  \node[initial, state]   (A)              {$0$};
  \node[state]            (C) [right=of A] {$2$};
  \node[state]            (D) [above=of C] {$3$};
  \node[state]            (E) [right=of D] {$4$};
  \node[state]            (F) [below=of E] {$5$};
  \node[state, accepting] (G) [right=of F] {$6$};

  \path (A) edge [above]     (C)
   (C) edge [above]     (D)
   (D) edge [above]     (E)
   (E) edge [above]     (F)
   (F) edge [above]     (G)
   (A) edge [bend left=80,looseness=1.7] (G);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the `bbox` library was removed from TikZ with version 3.1.6 due to licensing issues: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases/tag/3.1.6